# Flutter place an image inside another image

Tags: flutter

[image: Desktop image]
I'm creating an app where I'd like to place an image(A) inside another image(B). Basically the image of the desktop would act like as a container and the earth image would be its child. The desired output is that of a desktop with the earth image as it's wallpaper. Any suggestions on how to go about this in Flutter?
[image: Earth Image]

Comment: You can try with `Stack` widget .

Answer (score 1):

Use a **Stack** with an **Image** widget for the desktop image below, another **Image** widget for the earth image placed on top of the other wrapped inside a **Positioned** widget (since you need to line it up exactly at the specific coordinates so it lands right on the monitor**. You could also wrap the earth **Image** widget inside a **ClipRRect** for added styling.

Kind of like:

```dart
- Stack
   - Image (desktop)
   - Positioned (apply the top, left coordinates, etc.)
     - Image (earth)
```